# Socket.io connection event not fired

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am beginner to socket.io and trying to make simple hello world like program. It looks like my index.html page loads and connects to the server successfully but the server is not firing the "connection" event. I am sharing my code so that you can figure out what am I doing wrong here.

**app.js**

```
var app = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io'), fs = require('fs');

app.createServer(function(req,res){

console.log(req.url);

switch(req.url){
    case '/':
        fs.readFile('./index.html',function(err,data){
            if(err){
                res.end('Error');
                throw err;
            }

            res.writeHead(200,{"Context-type":"text/html"});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
        break;
    case '/socket.io.js':
        fs.readFile('./socket.io.js',function(err,data){
            if(err){
                res.end('Error');
                throw err;
            }

            res.writeHead(200,{"Context-type":"text/javascript"});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
}
}).listen(8888);
ios = io.listen(app);
console.log("Listening..");


ios.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
console.log('connection established.'); //this doesn't show up in CLI
});
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
<script src="socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The solution offered you works.  Replying with only "you're so wrong" with no further explanation is not very constructive.

Comment: you can't just declare "fs" variable without the var keyword. Moreover you didn't tell what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I hit return in front of the `require('fs')` and clearly forgot to add `var`.  It's not my job, as a volunteer to *tell* you what's wrong with your code.  It's yours to figure it out from the code or ask for help if you can't.  This is a volunteer organization,  and no one owes anyone anything other than common courtesy.

Comment: I tried my best figuring out myself but failed that's why I am here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out myself. All I had to do was to

```
server = require('http').createServer()
```

and then pass that server to the listener of socket io i.e.

```
io.listen(server);
```

What I was doing wrong that I was passing `app = require('http');` to the `io.listen(app)`